# VBA in MS Access linking to Word - error code 5981

Tags: ms-access, ms-word

I have an Access database which creates custom Word documents based on data in the database.  I have been running it successfully for the past 10 years through multiple computer and software upgrades.
I have just installed the program on a new computer (Windows 7) and I am getting an ***error 5981 - Could not open macro storage***.

The code is tripping at the ** line below:

```
Public Function CreateIndividualizedReport(FileDescription As String, FormTemplate As String, ClientFile As String, CallTheFile As String, Optional ClientType As Integer) As Boolean
    CreateIndividualizedReport = False

    Set glbWordObj = New Word.Application

    FilePath = DLookup("FilePath", "tblFileLocation", "FileDescription = '" & FileDescription & "'")
    **Set WordObjDoc = glbWordObj.Documents.Add(FilePath)**
```

I have searched online for this but all solutions have either not worked (renaming the `Normal.dot` file) or seem to be for much older versions of windows (most posts of this error seem to date from the early 2000's)

Anyone seen this problem recently or used different code to interface with Word?

Comment: It works for me (Access 2010 / Win 7). Can you manually open a Word document with that template?

Comment: Just a thought: is the Document at FilePath either Trusted or in a Trusted folder?

Comment: Adding the network location to the list of trusted locations, as suggested by @bibadia, fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced (and solved) this problem by:

1. Right-clicking the Word file in the Windows Explorer
2. Selecting properties
3. Unblocking the file (a checkbox at the bottom).

**Note:** This checkbox does not always show. It only appears when a file was sent to you from another computer. Windows 10 then marks the file as 'unsafe' until you check this box manually.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me for a similar problem. Note that you may have to also unblock the template file if you use Documents.Add

Answer (score 1):

There is a very long (and interesting) discussion of a similar error here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/accessdev/thread/5dfefcc5-0483-4190-890e-d90947c2a507

Bottom line: make the Word Application visible before you run the line to add your document.